# my jquery navbar does not appear in IE8

Tags: jquery

I've been searching an answer for that for a bit and I'm not able to find an answer to my dilema. The problem is probably simple enough but i've been having a nightmare with it.

I have a navbar powered with jquery that changes the background image when you hover and click on it. Once the click action is done, there is a fade to display the other image and also hide one div and show the other.

The code works perfectly fine in Firefox and chrome but stupid IE display's only a grey bar. When you click somewhere on the bar though, the div change works so i'm not sure what is wrong there.

To view the page click [here](http://www.cuisi-fit.com)

Here's the code:

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
            navigationPrimary();
            menuAction();

            $("#pagePlan").hide();
            $("#pagePortes").hide();
            $("#pageAutre").hide();

            function menuAction() {             
            $("#menu li.acceuil").click(function(){
                $("#main").show();
                $("#pagePlan").hide();
                $("#pagePortes").hide();
                $("#pageAutre").hide();
                $("#menu li.acceuil a").css("background-position","0px -100px");
                $("#menu li.plan a").css("background-position","-150px 0px");   
                $("#menu li.portes a").css("background-position","-300px 0px");
                $("#menu li.services a").css("background-position","-450px 0px");
                $("#header img.estim").show();
                return false;                       
            });


            $("#menu li.plan").click(function(){
                $("#main").hide();
                $("#pagePlan").show();
                $("#pagePortes").hide();
                $("#pageAutre").hide();
                $("#menu li.acceuil a").css("background-position","0px 0px");
                $("#menu li.plan a").css("background-position","-150px -100px");    
                $("#menu li.portes a").css("background-position","-300px 0px");
                $("#menu li.services a").css("background-position","-450px 0px");
                $("#header img.estim").hide();
                return false;                   
            });

            $("#menu li.portes").click(function(){
                $("#main").hide();
                $("#pagePlan").hide();
                $("#pagePortes").show();
                $("#pageAutre").hide();
                $("#menu li.acceuil a").css("background-position","0px 0px");
                $("#menu li.plan a").css("background-position","-150px 0px");   
                $("#menu li.portes a").css("background-position","-300px -100px");
                $("#menu li.services a").css("background-position","-450px 0px");
                $("#header img.estim").hide();      
                return false;                   
            });

            $("#menu li.services").click(function(){
                $("#main").hide();
                $("#pagePlan").hide();
                $("#pagePortes").hide();
                $("#pageAutre").show();
                $("#menu li.acceuil a").css("background-position","0px 0px");
                $("#menu li.plan a").css("background-position","-150px 0px");   
                $("#menu li.portes a").css("background-position","-300px 0px");
                $("#menu li.services a").css("background-position","-450px -100px");
                $("#header img.estim").hide();  
                return false;                       
            });
            }


        });

        function navigationPrimary() {
        $('#menu li').removeClass('hover');
        $('#menu li a')
            .css({ opacity: 1.0 })
            .mouseover(function() { 
                $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0.0}, 300);
                })
            .mouseout(function() {
                $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);
            });
        }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you getting errors in IE? Also, can you check your post for correctness...looks like code is missing or not getting displayed properly.

Comment: @matthewpavkov I fixed the code display thank you for pointing it out. For errors in IE. I don't get any errors from the browser per say, just the jquery not being displayed. Thanks for taking time to look at my question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the LI's in your UL are all floating, but you aren't clearing the float. Try adding this to your css, and then adding class clearfix to your #menu ul

```
/* >> The Magnificent CLEARFIX: Updated to prevent margin-collapsing on child elements << j.mp/bestclearfix */
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
  content: "\0020"; display: block; height: 0; visibility: hidden;  
} 

.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
/* Fix clearfix: blueprintcss.lighthouseapp.com/projects/15318/tickets/5-extra-margin-padding-bottom-of-page */
.clearfix { zoom: 1; }
```

Clearfix compliments of html5boilerplate

Comment: Thanks for your answer but sadly it did not fix my problem :(